# Issue only on the second time running

Tags: vba, ms-access

I wrote a label printer function for an analytical standards solution register.
I got a combobox that’s populated from a sql query and contain 4 fields. The combo is showing the available label templates. I try to set default selection so the label template will match the bottle size. I got a runtime error 3420 the second time I use the function. It works the first time and it looks like it goes out of scope to the second time. I have tried to refresh the recordset in every possible way .

Private Sub SettDefaultMallDueToVolyme(Volyme As Double, List As ComboBox, FildName As String)

```
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer       
    For i = 0 To List.ListCount Step 1
        List = List.ItemData(i)
        Set rec = List.Recordset
       
        If Not rec Is Nothing And rec.RecordCount > 0 Then
            If Volyme <= CDbl(rec(FildName)) Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        rec.Close
      Set rec = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

move Set rec = Nothing after the Next I

```
  End If
  rec.Close
  Next i
  Set rec = Nothing
End Sub
```